# ReadAsAsync JSON with non-static datamodels into model

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-4.8

The following is a model based on the response from an API (using sample data):

```
public class SchoolInfoModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public List<SchoolTypeModel> SchoolTypes { get; set; }
}
```

The `SchoolTypeModel` is where I'm stuck. The `SchoolType` will return a list but the content of the list might contain one other model or two other models or more. Basically a list of a number of different models. But I do not know in advance which models I receive. How do I map these?

Examples of "SchoolType" models I can receive:

```
public class HighSchoolModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
    public bool BA { get; set; }
    public bool CP { get; set; }
    public bool HU { get; set; }
    public bool MN { get; set; }
    public bool TI { get; set; }
}

public class SpecialPurposeSchoolModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
    public bool AH { get; set; }
}
```

I have a total of about 10 different types of school.

Comment: The usual way is to create a custom converter that analyses the JSON and decides which object it will be. But that can get complicated and brittle. Is this .NET 6?

Comment: You'd have the same problem with any generic method or collection, not just `ReadAsJsonAsync<T>`. All the types need to either be `T` or implement `T` to begin with. That `T` could be an interface or a base class. [Polymorphic deserialization](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#using-type-discriminators) will be introduced in .NET 7 anyway. You'll have to use JSON.NET in previous versions. The *client* will have to cooperate and specify the type eg in a ` "$type"` attribute

Comment: This is unfortunately .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: Your DTOs don't *have* to match your business model. You can have a DTO that can handle all possible properties and map it to separate types once it's loaded. Another option is to replace the extra "properties" with a single `Dictionary<string,bool>` property

Comment: Most .NET Framework projects use JSON.NET, which does support polymorphic deserialization. It's not clear that you even need multiple types though. The extra properties can easily be flags

Comment: I updated your tags. The answer really depends on what packages and versions you are using. You really need to be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can achieve this with JSON.Net (which means it will work in .NET Framework 4.8). You can create a custom converter to figure out what properties exist in this JSON and use that to determine which type to deserialise to. For example:

```
public class SchoolTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        => objectType == typeof(SchoolTypeModel);


    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);


        if (obj.ContainsKey("AH")) 
        {
            return obj.ToObject<SpecialPurposeSchoolModel>(serializer);
        }

        if (obj.ContainsKey("BA"))
        {
            return obj.ToObject<HighSchoolModel>(serializer);
        }

        // We have no idea what this is, so panic
        throw new Exception("No idea what to do with this value!");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // We are only using this to read JSON
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And to read the JSON:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new SchoolTypeConverter());

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SchoolInfoModel>(yourJsonString,
    settings); // Pass in the settings object we created above
```

Comment: This only works if non of the other types have "AH" or "BA"... IMHO better to use a type discriminator.

Comment: I know, it's just an example

Comment: Great suggestion. Instead of using ReadAsAsync on my HttpResponseMessage, I'll use ReadAsStringAsync and then do my own parser on the string. Thanks!